# Plotting two y axes on the same scale on an implot (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have an image plot, representing a matrix, with two axes. The y axis on th left of my image plot represents the rows and the x axis represents the column, while each grid cell represents the value as a function of x and y.

I'd like to plot my y-axis in another form on the right side of my image plot, which takes on much smaller values, but should still be in the same positions as the y-axis on the left, as the values are just different forms of one another. The problem is that when I use `fig.twinx()`and go to plot the y axis, it doesn't even show up! Does anyone know what's gong on? Thanks.

Current code:

```
# Setup the figure
fig5 = pyplot.figure(5, figsize=(10,9), facecolor='white')
pyplot.gcf().clear()
# plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=20)
# plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=20)
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 18})
fig5ax = pyplot.axes()

# Code to calculate extent based on min/max range and my x values

implot = pyplot.imshow(valgrid, extent=MyExtent , aspect='auto', vmin = myVmin, vmax = myVmax) 

fig5ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.ticker.FixedFormatter([str(x) for x in ranges]))
fig5ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.ticker.FixedLocator(ranges))

fig5Ax2 = fig5ax.twinx()
fig5Ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.ticker.FixedFormatter([str(x) for x in time]))
# Setting locater the same as ranges, because I want them to line up
# as they are different forms of the same y value
fig5Ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.ticker.FixedLocator(ranges))

pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Does any of this have any relationship with MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was:

`fig5Ax2.yaxis.set_view_interval(minRange, maxRange)`